# Brand new hammer drill covered in oil

Tags: drill

I bought a brand new hammer drill from Valu. When I took it out of the box it was covered in oil. Is this normal and is it safe to use?

Comment: Probably an anti-corrosion oil to prevent rust.  Wipe it off before use or have your hands feel icky/sticky after use.

Comment: Its not normal, but machine oil does get on compnemts. Its usually cleaned off. It does not mean that thd drill is faulty

Comment: it probably got really hot during shipping. If it has batteries, it could be a concern but if not, it's 100% fine.